# C++ Inheritance / #include (Multiple compiler errors)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, include

this is my first post, and I'm only a first year programming student. So please excuse any amateur/novice language or poor understanding from me, cheers =)

For my Application Modelling assignment, I've been given the task of creating a library system, using object oriented programming. I have currently set up the classes for this, with all the methods (gets, sets etc) and I have absolutely **no syntax errors**.

However, I have a multitude (192 and counting...) of compiler errors.

I have a feeling this is because of how I have used **inheritance**.

I have used the following classes (both with source and header files):

-Copy
-Copy Handler
-Book 
-Book Handler
-Catalog
-Catalog Handler
-Member
-Member Handler
-MembershipApplications
-MembershipApplicationsHandler
-Invoice
-Invoice Handler
-Order
-OrderHandler
-Orders
-OrdersHandler

(The handler classes are simply used to create their corresponding object, e.g. copy handler creates and returns a copy object.)

Copy being the first class and OrdersHandler being the final class I have used inheritance and includes to link them all together.

***At the start of "Copy.h" I have typed this:***

```
#pragma once
#include <array>   //for array used later on
#include <vector>  //for std::vector
#include <string>  //for std::string
using namespace std;

class Copy:
    public CopyHandler //Inheriting from copy handler class
```

***At the start of "CopyHandler.h" I have typed this:***

```
#pragma once
#include "Copy.h"
class CopyHandler:

public Book //inheritance from book
```

***At the start of "Book.h" I have typed this:***

```
#pragma once
#include "CopyHandler.h"
using namespace std;
class Book:
    public BookHandler
```

So essentially, in each header file I include the previous file and "public" the next file. However, this still causes me 3 digits worth of errors...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers =)

Comment: `Copy` depends on `CopyHandler` so `CopyHandler` must be declared first. You have it the other way around.

Comment: So, I should essentially do, OrderHandler at the bottom, and Copy at the top?
=)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your problem? Perhaps provide us with more code, what kind of errors do you get etc.

Answer (score 0):

`(The handler classes are simply used to create their corresponding object, e.g. copy handler creates and returns a copy object.)`

That being said, I think you have your understanding inheritance syntax flipped. `CopyHandler` should inherit from `Copy`, yes? If so, the syntax is:

`class CopyHandler : public Copy`

Your errors stem from:

`Copy` inherits from `CopyHandler` but `Copy` does not know that. `CopyHandler` has not been declared yet.

Inheritance is done by the child class(initiated by the child class) not by the parent class forcing inheritance down, as your syntax would suggest.

[Good syntax tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson20.html)

Comment: I shall give this a try and get back to you asap =)

Thank you.

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately it only made the errors worse. =(

I switched the inheritance for the handlers around, but I still get the same errors, if not more. =(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question does not make sense when it comes to inheritance. What is your goal? The implementation class should be the child class. The other errors are probably because of the many other errors in your code.